# Enable binding breaks when observable array updated via Ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/24/

I have a button (Remove inputs) with enable and css bindings that are returned when an observable array contains more than 2 items.

```
<button data-bind="click: removeInput, enable: Integers().length >2, css { red: Integers().length >2 }">Remove Input</button>
```

I also have a function (loadIntegerSorter) that sets the observable array to contain 2 items.

```
self.loadIntegerSorter = function () {
    self.Integers([new integer(0, 0, 0), new integer(0, 0, 0)]);
};
```

I also have a save function that submits via ajax. Within the success callback, loadIntegerSorter is called.

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.Status == "success") {
        isvm.loadSortedIntegers();
    }
}
```

However, this seems to break the enable binding. The CSS binding behaves as expected with the array items = 2. But the Enable binding does not. I can run loadIntegerSorter outside of the Ajax function successfully so I suppose this is a synchronization problem but I don't know what the solution is.

The fiddle I've linked to doesn't fully demonstrate the problem because it depends on making a genuine Ajax request. But I hope it shows enough to understand.

**Elaboration:**

This results in the expected behaviour from the enable binding:

```
self.save = function () {
    self.isloading();
};
```

But this doesn't:

```
self.save = function () {
    $.ajax("/Home/Index", {
        data: ko.toJSON(self.integerSorter),
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        context: self,
        success: function (result) {
            this.isloading();
        }
    });
};
```

And nor does this:

```
self.save = function () {
    self.isloading();

    $.ajax("/Home/Index", {
        data: ko.toJSON(self.integerSorter),
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        context: self,
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });
};
```

Whatever the cause of the problem, it seems to be related to the ajax call.

Comment: You can do a genuine ajax request on jsfiddle. There is a tab on the left where they explain how.

Comment: Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/24/ I've tried to implement echo/Json but I'm getting the error: Request is not defined.

Comment: don't worry - the problem should be solved anyway. Check out my updated answer. Please note that my answer is based on revision 23 of your fiddle. The new edits you've made introduces new errors which I don't cover.

Answer (score 1):

1)

Inside of your `self.save` function you're calling

```
self.isLoading(true);
```

Which yields

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'self.isLoading(true)')

telling you that `self.isLoading` is not declared anywhere in your code. This will break code execution even before the ajax request is sent.

---

2)

Same as 1) but this time for `self.msgbox.status()`. Undeclared: will break your code.

---

3)

The function `self.loadIntegerSorter` appears as `self.loadSortedIntegers` in the success function. Also, the `self.save` function appears declared two times. The second one will ovverride the first, but I guess the first one is there just in the fiddle.

---

4)

Inside of the success function, `result.Status` doesn't have any sense. You must understand that `result` is just a string of plain text, accessing the `Status` property of a string will result in an error. Perhaps you expect the response to be a JSON object with a `Status` property? If that is the case, you have to deserialize the string either by yourself (`JSON.parse(response)`) or by telling jQuery to do that for you (replace `$.ajax` with `$.getJSON`).

However, it may also be that you're not receiving any JSON back and you just wanted to access the response status, assuming you could do it that way. You can't. Being inside of a success function, you already know that your request has been successfully sent and a response received. No need to check it again.

---

5)

You're calling the `loadSortedIntegers()` method on the variable `isvm`. That's a totally wrong approach, even if it should work now it may cause huge troubles in the future. `isvm` is a global variable you use to contain an instance of your viewModel. The success function is contained in the viewModel itself, you should access it's own methods with `this` or `self`. A class should not access an instance of itself with a global variable. Question: how can I make `this` and/or `self` available in the success function? `this` can be reached by setting the context property to your `$.ajax` object. Exactly as you write `success: function(){}` you should write, just before that, `context: this` or, in your case, `context: self`.

Do that, and then just change the success function contents with `this.loadSortedIntegers()`.

---

I've took the liberty to make some edits to your fiddle. Take your time to examine the difference [here](http://www.diffchecker.com/47f0e6ju) and to run it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/27/).

Comment: Point taken - thanks for explaining. None of the above seems to have worked though.

Comment: I don't have access to a proper computer now, but I'll check your fiddle again as soon as possible. In the meanwhile, you may wanna put a breakpoint inside of your success function and inspect it with chrome dev tools. Just write "debugger" inside of it and launch it with chrome dev tools enabled.

Comment: Points 1), 2) and 3): These refer to irrelevant features of my application that I hadn't yet deleted from the fiddle. Apologies if I linked to the wrong version. This one should be better: http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/24/ Point 4) Status is a Json object returned from the server. It seems to be working okay. Point 5) I've made those corrections and still no success. :( Thanks for analysing my code but I don't feel any closer to the solution. As I mentioned, the CSS binding behaves as expected so I don't understand why the enable binding doesn't.

Comment: the enable binding is working as expected in my fiddle. Irrelevant features or not, they can crash the code and prevent the execution of every single line which comes after. The same foes for Status. Since you're not deserializing result, it will remain a simple string and accessing .Status of a string will cause the code to crash.

Comment: fiddle 24 contains a new error. new Request.JSON is not valid JavaScript syntax. The object "Request" doesn't exists.

Comment: The enable binding works as expected in my fiddle too. But the fiddle doesn't replicate the ajax call in my application. Even if I apply all your suggestions, I'm still out of luck. I'll edit my original post to elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use valueHasMutated to push update for observable directly:

```
self.loadIntegerSorter = function () {
    self.Integers([new integer(0, 0, 0), new integer(0, 0, 0)]);
    self.Integers.valueHasMutated();

};
```